# Semantic UI React - Input in Dropdown does not allow space

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I have a dropdown with nested text inputs. After adding `onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()}` to the inputs I am able to select an input and type in it, however as soon as I press the space bar the dropdown is closed.

I have worked out that adding `multiple` or `closeOnChange={false}` to the dropdown keeps the dropdown open, however the `onChange` of the input is not fired, which means that the space is not added to the string and it effectively results in a noop.

I have created a simple pen to show the issue which may be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-hhxng).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is directly related to your issue, but I had the same problem and realized it was caused by adding a `.trim()` in my `onChange()` function updating the Input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution would be to add

```
    onKeyUp = {(e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === 32) {
        e.target.value = e.target.value + " " 
        e.stopPropagation()}
      }
    }
```

to the `Input`

Comment: Certainly a bit hacky, but it works! Thanks so much for the assist.

Comment: After playing around with the solution for a while I noticed that this only works when adding a space at the end of the string. Ended up changing the `if` logic to 
`if (e.keyCode === 32) {const value = e.target.value; const index = e.target.selectionStart; e.target.value = \`${value.slice(0, index)} ${value.slice(index)}\`; e.target.selectionStart = index+1; e.target.selectionEnd = index+1; e.stopPropagation();}`
This is however a bit sluggish. Would love to hear any other suggestions.

Comment: Is it laggish on production build too? This might not help much but sure looks better: try first moving this logic to a function (e.g. onKeyUp) out and just having onKeyUp = {onKeyUp}.

Answer (score 0):

The `onKeyUp` workaround did not work for me, but I found [another one](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/4374#issuecomment-1208134447) (thanks arjitacharya1994) which works. Just add the following to the `Input`:

```
onKeyDown={(e) => e.code === 'Space' ? e.stopPropagation() : null}
```